# giving color to substring after javascript split()

Tags: javascript, html

i want to print the text entered in textarea with different colors means i am seperating the string with split() method it works fine then i want to print the substrings in textarea with colors how is it possible

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function init() {
    document.getElementById('txtarea2').focus();
}
function setcolor() {
var str=document.getElementById('txtarea2').value;
var str1=str.split(":");
var first= str1[0];
var second=str1[1];
document.getElementById('txtarea1').value= first + second;
document.getElementById('txtarea2').focus();
}
</script>
<body onload="init()">
<textarea id="txtarea1" rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>
<textarea id="txtarea2" rows="3" cols="20" onChange="setcolor()"></textarea>
</body>
```

please help me

Comment: is it necessary to use textarea? I mean you can make a div and append two different <a>'s having different colors to it

Answer (score 2):

make an empty div and use it to append

```
<div id="newDiv"></div>
```

then create and append two different tags to to this div

```
first = '<a style="color:red">'+first+'</a>';
second = '<a style="color:blue">'+second+'</a>';
document.getElementById("newDiv").innerHTML=first+second;
```

Comment: <span> tags can be better than <a> tags

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
document.getElementById('txtarea1').style.color = 'red';
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to have multiple colors in a single HTML textarea like you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have different color text in a textarea.

You would need to use a [rich editor](http://ckeditor.com/) to do that.

If the text is not editable, than use a div/pre to output it and color it with normal css tags.